# Can someone explain why the effective potential should be IR cutoff independent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I'm studying renormalization in my bachelor but there is something I don't understand:

In $\phi^4$ scalar field theory, What does it mean that effective potential is depending on the cutoff? and Why should it be independent from the infrared cutoff?